# Why is this code not replacing data in a text file?

Tags: c#, edi, x12

I'm working on a small app which should read a file (ANSI 835) and replace data at certain positions with generic data. Basically I'm trying to scrub a person's first and last name from the file.

The line I'm searching for that contains the name looks like this:

```
NM1*QC*1*Doe*John*R***MI*010088307    01~
```

My code looks like this:

```
string[] input_file = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
string output_file = @"c:\scrubbed.txt";

foreach (string file in input_file)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("NM1*QC"))
        {
            line.Split('*')[1] = "Lastname";
            line.Split('*')[2] = "Firstname";
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(output_file, lines);
}
```

The `File.WriteAllLines` works, but the data isn't being changed. I'm trying to get any line that starts with `NM1*QC` to look like this:

```
NM1*QC*1*Lastname*Firstname*R***MI*010088307    01~
```

There are many lines in the file that start with `NM1*QC`. What's the proper way to 'find and replace' and then create a new file in this situation?

As always, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calls to `String.Split` return variables that you neither capture, nor use, they do not change the underlying string.  So your code equates to this:

```
 if (line.StartsWith("NM1*QC"))
 {
     string[] split1 = line.Split('*')[1] = "Lastname";
     string[] split2 = line.Split('*')[2] = "Firstname";
 }
```

You would need to take the results of `split1` and `split2` and use those to recreate your string.  Here is how I would re-write your code:

```
string[] input_file = (string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop));
string output_file = @"c:\scrubbed.txt";
foreach (string file in input_file)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    for (int i=0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        string line = lines[i];
        if (line.StartsWith("NM1*QC"))
        {
            string[] values = line.Split('*');
            values[1] = "Lastname";
            values[2] = "Firstname";
            lines[i] = String.Join("*", values);
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(output_file, lines);
}
```

Notice I am recombining the individual values using the `String.Join` method, and inserting the new string back into the array of lines.  That will then get written out as you expect.

Comment: thank you for the reply :) however, the `lines[i]` line throws 2 errors: `cannot convert 'string[]' to 'string'` and `cannot convert 'string' to 'string[]'`

Comment: @JeffBrady I think you have a typo, can you possibly update your question with your new code, or post that particular line here as a comment?

Comment: `lines[i] = String.Join(values, '*');` is the line giving the errors

Comment: Sorry, I had that backwards, it should be: `lines[i] = String.Join("*", values);`.  Will update answer to reflect.

Comment: Interesting, that did work, but the resulting output is `NM1*Lastname*Firstname*1*Doe*John*R***MI*010088307    01~` .. it replaced the `QC` with `*Lastname*Firstname*` :D It's inserting (joining?) the data as opposed to replacing it.

Comment: Still doesn't sound right, does the `lines` array have the number of elements you would expect?  So it looks like it should have 10 elements (0..9); after the `if()` block it should still have 10 but as you describe it sounds like it would have 11?

Comment: i changed `values[1]` and `values[2]` to `values[2]` and `values[3]` respectively, and it worked properly. I think the whole 'NM1*QC' may be being treated as `values[0]` ?

Comment: Yes, the array indexes are 0 based.  Glad you got it to work!

Comment: Per my discussion with Jon below, I mistakenly had 1 and 2 in my example code.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are creating a temporary array:

```
line.Split('*')
```

And you are changing its contents:

```
line.Split('*')[1] = "Lastname";
```

After the line has been executed the reference to this temporary array is lost and along with it go your changes.

In order to persist the changes you need to write directly to `lines`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
{
    var line = lines[i];

    if (!line.StartsWith("NM1*QC"))
    {
        continue;
    }

    var parts = line.Split('*');
    parts[3] = "Lastname";
    parts[4] = "Firstname";

    lines[i] = string.Join("*", parts);
}
```

Comment: Although correct does it not answer the question _"What's the proper way to 'find and replace' and then create a new file in this situation?"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Was still writing :)

Comment: @Jon thanks for the explanation .. the temporary array thing makes complete sense. I see what you're doing with the code, however the `lines[i]` line throws 2 errors: `cannot convert 'string[]' to 'string'` and `cannot convert 'string' to 'string[]'`

Comment: the line `lines[i] = string.Join(parts, "*");` should read `lines[i] = string.Join("*", parts);` but results in an output of `NM1*Lastname*Firstname*1*Doe*John*R***MI*010088307 01~` as opposed to replacing the last and first name in the string.

Comment: @JeffBrady: Fixed the first part. For the second, I just copied the indexes from your own example blindly (mea culpa). The correct indexes seem to be 3 and 4 (edited as well).

Comment: doh .. i didn't even realize that's where you were getting the 1 and 2 from! I'm not sure why i had 1 and 2 in there.